# How is Javac compiled to an executable?

Tags: java, javac

`Javac` itself is written in Java but it is provided as an executable file when we download the `JDK`. What tools are used to compile the Java sources of `Javac` to an executable?

Comment: The Graal Compiler should do that but it basically includes a stripped-down version of the JVM inside the executable which is not the case with `Javac`, I assume

Comment: Any self-respecting compiler can compile itself.  Since Javac is written in Java, you should be able to compile the Javac source using Javac.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I believe this would only be true if Javac compiled sources to machine code but it's not. It compiles them to bytecode... So yes, it can compile itself into bytecode, but how do we get the machine code?

Comment: The same way you get the machine code for any other Java executable, I presume: using a JIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JDK, called [boot JDK](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/build/doc/building.html) which is usually the N-1 version of the JDK you're building, plus C/C++ compilers. At least for OpenJDK, the [supported toolchains](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Build/Supported+Build+Platforms) by Oracle are [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/) on Linux, [clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) on macOS, and [msvc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/?view=msvc-160) on Windows. Additionally, SAP maintains the AIX build using [XLC](https://www.ibm.com/id-en/marketplace/xl-cpp-linux-compiler-power).

Comment: Thanks! Do you have some more info on how I could compile it myself?

Comment: The boot JDK link is the step-by-step guide to do that. Note that while building on Linux is quite straightforward, building on Windows is really hard, follow each and every step mentioned in the link, and on macOS, you'll end up fighting the OS if the Xcode version is different. Also, SSD helps a lot.